# Create an Azure VM from an ISO stored in a blob

Tags: azure, blob, virtual-machine, storage, bootable

I have an ISO file from MSFT that is a bootable DVD.   I uploaded it to a storage account and stored it in a blob in Azure.   Now I want to use it to create a VM.   When I select to create a VM, I do not see that as an option.   Any ideas how I can provision this?   My laptop does not have enough resources to create a Hyper-V VM to then upload the disk.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure you do not have console access to a VM. The only way to access a VM is some kind of remote access like RDP, PowerShell Remoting, or SSH.

I do not know what your ISO contains, but I assume that it is some kind of installation ISO in which state you do not have remote access but would need console access (which is not possible in Azure).

If I am wrong and you have an ISO file that directly boots into an operating system like many Linux distributions do then you could use an ISO to VHD converter (see e.g. https://mcloudinfo.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/convert-a-wim-or-iso-file-to-vhdx/). If that is the case I would download that ISO file inside from a VM, convert it to VHD, and put it back into your BLOB storage in Azure. After that you have to create a new VM via PowerShell.

But remember, your ISO should then contain an operating system that directly gets an IP address via DHCP and has open ports for remote access. Otherwise you cannot access it.

Also to note, Azure currently supports only VHD, not VHDX.

Comment: So I learned the latest version needs to be 'imported' to powershell module.   Now i need to figure out how to get it to create the VHDx file for output...   but I think this might just work!    Thanks for the great find!