# Convert iso file into .VHD file that is to be deployed in azure

Tags: powershell, azure, hyper-v, iso, vhd

I have tried several method for conversion ( using MVMC tools and using Hyper-V modules in powershell ) of ISO file into .VHD file but the thus converted .VHD file when deployed did not work in azure. 
I am searching for a best approach to convert ISO file into .VHD file and thus deploy it into azure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an Azure VM from an ISO stored in a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087352/create-an-azure-vm-from-an-iso-stored-in-a-blob)

Comment: create a vm from the iso and upload the vhd?

Answer (score 0):

If your ISO is for a Linux distribution, Azure has [specific requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/classic/create-upload-vhd) for preparing the image before uploading.  I would follow the instructions in the official documentation in that instance (i.e. create a VM, modify it as instructed, upload).

If your ISO is for a version of Windows, creating a SYSPREP'd VHD seems like a valid approach.  My go-to tool for this in PowerShell is [Convert-WindowsImage](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Convert-WindowsImageps1-0fe23a8f).  Don't forget to use `-VhdFormat VHD` -- Convert-WindowsImage creates a VHDX by default, but Azure requires the VHD format.